# Convert nested lists to custom data type

Tags: haskell

I am trying to convert nested lists into a custom type called `Mydata` using a list comprehension as follows:

```
main = do
    let a = [["12.345", "1", "4.222111"],
             ["31.2", "12", "9.1234"],
             ["43.111111", "3", "8.13"],
             ["156.112121", "19", "99.99999"]]
    let b = foo a
    print b

foo xss = [(xs,xs) | xs <- xss, xs <- xss]
    where
         xs = Mydata (read xs!!0 :: Float) (read xs!!1 :: Int) (read xs!!2 :: Float)

data Mydata = Mydata {valA :: Float, valB :: Int, valC :: Float}
```

When I run my program I get the following error:

```
1.hs:11:28:
    Couldn't match expected type `String' with actual type `Mydata'
    In the first argument of `read', namely `xs'
    In the first argument of `(!!)', namely `read xs'
    In the first argument of `Mydata', namely `(read xs !! 0 :: Float)'
```

Can anyone help me figure out what the problem is? Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to take a line at a time, so "foo" will convert a single list of strings into a single "Mydata". Then map foo over your list of lists to get a list of Mydata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xs` definition in list comprehension is (perhaps unintentionally) recursive, and makes no sense. Possible implementation follows:

```
data Mydata = Mydata {valA :: Float, valB :: Int, valC :: Float} deriving Show

-- rely on type inference instead of specifying explicit type for each `read'
dataFromList [a, b, c] = Mydata (read a) (read b) (read c)
dataFromList _ = error "dataFromList: not enough arguments in list"

main = do
    let a = [["12.345", "1", "4.222111"],
             ["31.2", "12", "9.1234"],
             ["43.111111", "3", "8.13"],
             ["156.112121", "19", "99.99999"]]
    let b = map dataFromList a
    -- alternatively
    -- let b = [dataFromList triple | triple <- a]
    print b
```

Answer (score 3):

{- 
I'm going to take the opportunity to tell you some other things I think will help in the long run as well as fix the problem.
-}

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Maybe
import Network.CGI.Protocol (maybeRead)
```

{-
The Control.Applicative lets me use `<$>` and `<*>` which are really handy functions for working with loads of things (more later).
I'm going to use `maybeRead` later. I don't know why it's not in `Data.Maybe`.

Data structure first. I've derived show so we can print Mydata. 
-}

```
data Mydata = Mydata {valA :: Float, 
                      valB :: Int, 
                      valC :: Float}
  deriving Show
```

{-
I've put `somedata` as a definition in the main body (you had `let a =` inside `main`), because I felt you were seriously overusing the IO monad.
It's worth trying to do as much as possible in pure world, because it makes debugging much easier.
Maybe in your actual problem, you'll have read `somedata` in from somewhere, but for writing the functions, 
having a bit of test data like this lying around is a big bonus. (Try though to only mention `somedata` as a definition 
here once, so you don't get a rash of global constants!)
-}

```
somedata = [["12.345", "1", "4.222111"],
            ["31.2", "12", "9.1234"],
            ["43.111111", "3", "8.13"],
            ["156.112121", "19", "99.99999"]]

somewrong = [ ["1",   "2",   "3"     ],    -- OK
              ["1.0", "2",   "3.0"   ],    -- OK, same value as first one
              ["1",   "2.0", "3"     ],    -- wrong, decimal for valB
              ["",    "two",  "3.3.3"] ]   -- wrong, wrong, wrong.
```

{-
Let's write a function to read a single `Mydata`, but use `Maybe Mydata` so we can recover gracefully if it doesn't work out.
`maybeRead :: Read a => String -> Maybe a`, so it turns strings into `Just` what you want, or gives you `Nothing` if it can't.
This is better than simply crashing with an error message. 
(Better still would be to return `Either` an error message explaining the problem or the `Right` answer, but I'm going to skip that for today.)

I'm going to write this three ways, getting nicer and nicer.
-}

```
readMydata_v1 :: [String] -> Maybe Mydata
readMydata_v1 [as, bs, cs] = case (maybeRead as, maybeRead bs, maybeRead cs) of
   (Just a, Just b, Just c) -> Just $ Mydata a b c
   _                        -> Nothing
readMydata_v1 _ = Nothing    -- anything else is the wrong number of Strings
```

{-
so we look at `(maybeRead as, maybeRead bs, maybeRead cs)` and if they all worked, we make a `Mydata` out of them, then return `Just` the right answer,
but if something else happened, one of them was a `Nothing`, so we can't make a `Mydata`, and so we get `Nothing` overall.

Try it out in gchi with `map readMydata_v1 somedata` and `map readMydata_v1 somewrong`.

Notice how because I used the expression `Mydata a b c`, it forces the types of `a`, `b` and `c` to be `Float`, `Int` and `Float` in the `(Just a, Just b, Just c)` pattern.
That pattern is the output of `(maybeRead as, maybeRead bs, maybeRead cs)`, which forces the types of the three uses of `maybeRead` to be right - 
I don't need to give individual type signatures. Type signatures are really handy, but they're not pretty in the middle of a function.

Now I like using `Maybe`, but I don't like writing loads of `case` statements inside each other, so I could use the face that `Maybe` is a `Monad`.
See *Learn You a Haskell for Great Good* http://learnyouahaskell.com for more details about monads, but for my purposes here, it's like I can treat a `Maybe` value like it's `IO` even though it's not.
-}

```
readMydata_v2 :: [String] -> Maybe Mydata
readMydata_v2 [as,bs,cs] = do
      a <- maybeRead as
      b <- maybeRead bs
      c <- maybeRead cs
      return $ Mydata a b c
readMydata_v2 _ = Nothing    -- anything else is the wrong number of Strings
```

{-
I seem to write no error handling code! Aren't `Maybe` monads great! 
Here we take whatever `a` we can get out of `maybeRead as`, whatever `b` we can get from reading `bs` 
and whatever `c` we get from `cs`, and if that has all worked we get `Just $ Mydata a b c`. 
The `Maybe` monad deals with any `Nothing`s we get by stopping and returning `Nothing`, and wraps any correct answer in `Just`.

Whilst this is really nice, it doesn't feel very *functional programming*, so let's go the whole hog and make it `Applicative`.
You should read about `Applicative` in http://learnyouahaskell.com, but for now, lets just use it.

Whenever you find yourself writing

```
foo x y z = do
   thing1 <- something x
   thing2 <- somethingelse y
   thing3 <- anotherthing x z
   thing4 <- yetmore y y z
   return $ somefunction thing1 thing2 thing3 thing4
```

it means you're using a monad when you could more cleanly use an "applicative functor". 
All this means in practice is that you could have written that

```
foo x y z = somefunction  <$>  something x  <*>  somethingelse y  <*>  anotherthing x z  <*>  yetmore y y z
```

or if you prefer,

```
foo x y z = somefunction  <$>  something x  
                          <*>  somethingelse y  
                          <*>  anotherthing x z  
                          <*>  yetmore y y z
```

this is nicer because (a) it feels more like ordinary function application (notice that `<$>` works like `$` and `<*>` works like a space ) and (b) you don't need 
to invent names `thing1` etc.

It means find out the results of `something x` and `somethingelse y` and `anotherthing x z` and `yetmore y y z` then apply `somefunction` to the result.

Let's do `readMydata` the applicative way:
-}

```
readMydata_nice :: [String] -> Maybe Mydata
readMydata_nice [a,b,c] = Mydata <$> maybeRead a <*> maybeRead b <*> maybeRead c
readMydata_nice _       = Nothing
```

{-
Aaaahhhhh, so clean, so functional, so easy. Mmmmm. :) Think more, write less.

This means take the resuts of `maybeRead a` and `maybeRead b` and `maybeRead c` and apply `Mydata` to the result, but because everything is `Maybe`, if anything along the way is `Nothing`, the answer will be `Nothing`.

Again, you can test this out in ghci with `map readMydata_nice somedata` or `map readMydata_nice somewrong`

Anyway, lets write `main`, which is now more functional too.
-}

```
main = mapM_ print $ catMaybes $ map readMydata_nice somedata
```

{-
This takes each list of Strings in `somedata` and reads them as `Maybe Mydata`, then throws away the `Nothing`s and turns them into `IO` `print` commands and does them one after another.
`mapM_` works a bit like `map` but does every `IO` it creates. Because it's several `print`s, each one goes on a seperate line, which is much easier to read.

Here I've decided to use `catMaybes` to ignore the `Nothing` values and just print the ones that worked. In a real program,
I'd use `Either` like I said, so that I can pass an error message instead of silently ignoring wrong data. All the tricks we used on `Maybe` also work on `Either`.
-}

Answer (score 1):

In the definition

```
where
  xs = Mydata (read xs!!0 :: Float) (read xs!!1 :: Int) (read xs!!2 :: Float)
```

you are using `xs` on the left and the right-hand side of the definition. Therefore, it has to have the same type on both sides. The compiler assumes that the type of `xs` is `MyData` and you cannot apply `read` to a value of that type.