# How to read a string for a number starting with a decimal point in Haskell?

Tags: parsing, haskell, decimal-point

I'm a total Haskell beginner who just discovered that `read` spits out an exception when given a decimal number starting with `.` rather than a digit. For example, in ghci:

```
Prelude> read ".7" :: Float
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

I found [one discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641363/why-do-haskell-numerical-literals-need-to-start-and-end-with-digits) and it makes sense why surrounding `.` in numbers with digits is required in Haskell. [Another discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974669/haskell-cant-read-this-double-3-is-this-a-bug) is also somewhat helpful, but no one provides a solution of how to actually convert `".7"` to `0.7`.

So, I'm trying to extract data from a fixed-width format file containing fields with values like `.7`---is there a standard function or approach I can use to clean this up to a float `0.7`?

(Before I hit this issue, my basic ideas was to define a custom type for my data, use `splitWidth` in `Data.List.Split` to split each line into its fields, and then use `read` to convert each field into its correct type, trying to apply the functional goodness in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12188448/4280216) in the actual implementation.)

Comment: I'm uncertain what you are looking for.  You have mentioned an attempt but not shown any code.  Do you really just want `myRead = read . ('0':) :: String -> Float`?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Thanks, yes, that should do it! Your `myRead` won't work on negative numbers, but fortunately I don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thomas M. DuBuisson answered in a comment above, the obvious thing to do is `myRead = read . ('0':) :: String -> Float`. This works for me --- I won't ever be trying to read negative numbers, and I know which fields should be read as float. Thanks!